# SonarQube 9.9 discrepancy in the scan results

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint

Recently we have upgraded our Sonar Server from the “Community Edition Version 7.9.2 (build 30863)” to “Community Edition Version 9.9.1 (build 69595)”.

We had some customized Quality profiles along with default profiles on our server. All these profiles got migrated properly on the upgrade server.

However, while testing the scans on upgraded server, we observed that some of the Rules which are passing on older version are now failing and resulting into bugs on upgraded version.

We are running the scans on same source code and using same profiles on both these servers when we are getting this discrepancy in the scan results.

A couple of examples are:

Rule No: S3796 
Rule Description in old version: Callbacks of array methods should have return statements
Rule Description in upgraded version: Callbacks of array methods should have return statements
Scan result in old version: Rule is passed
Scan result in upgraded version: Rule resulted into BLOCKER Bug

Rule No: S3827
Rule Description in old version: Non-existent variables should not be referenced
Rule Description in upgraded version: Non-existent variables should not be referenced
Scan result in old version:Rule is passed
Scan result in upgraded version: Rule resulted in BLOCKER Bug

Can you please help us understand the possible causes for this discrepancy in the scan results on the older version vs the upgraded version?

Comment: They use different versions of their analyzers on each SonarQube version. It could be that the rule got improved and it is now triggered by your code. Is it a false positive?